# Use SVN with IntelliJ without command line

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, intellij-12

Is there a way to use SVN on IntelliJ without using the command line or extra software? All results online are either completely unhelpful or point to the command line. I would like to leverage IntelliJ's merge capabilities when I commit. I cannot switch to another method of version control.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `svn` is most certainly integrated in IntelliJ, and you can indeed do merging and branching without ever having to use the command line again :)

Firstly, you need to check that the plugin "Subversion Integration" is enabled (go to `Settings` -> `Plugins` and check there).

Once it's enabled, you can look under the `VCS` menu and see some useful menu items.

Start with VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Subversion.

Other useful actions you can find are for example VCS -> Merge from... and VCS -> Subversion -> many other options.

Good luck.